# How was this result obtained?

Tags: matlab

When I ran the following command in MATLAB:

```
x=zeros(size(30,1),1)
```

I got a `1x1` `double` matrix with the value `0`.

How is that?

Thanks.

Comment: You can execute code by highlighting it and pressing F9. This applies to partial code within longer one-liners.

Answer (score 4):

`size(30,1)` returns the the number of rows (indicated by `size(A,1)`) of the "matrix" `30`. Since your matrix has only one element, the number of rows is `1` which means `x` is a `1x1` matrix of zeros.